# What the difference between these two types of inheritance?

Tags: c#, oop, repository, idisposable

I'm coding a repository and i was with the following problem:

The code below shows an error as if the repository were inheriting the IRepository interface and type `T` was inheriting IDisposable

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, IDisposable
```

So, when i changed the inheritance order, the problem was solved

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IDisposable, IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

My solution for this problem its correct?

Comment: in first version, each `T` should be a class and implement IDisposable. In second version, your `GenericRepository<T>` class must implement IDisposable. This is not the same (and first version doesn't make much sense in a repository pattern logic)

Answer (score 3):

In your first code snippet the `IDisposable` is part of the constraint.

In your second code snippet, the `IDisposable` is an interface that your `GenericRepository<T>` implements.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, IDisposable
```

*constrains* type parameter T to implement `IDisposable`.

With the second code you show, it is the `GenericRepository<T>` which is required to *implement* `IDisposable` interface, no matter of what T is.

Answer (score 2):

The former:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, IDisposable
```

enforces the `IDisposable` constraint on type `T`, whereas:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IDisposable, IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

requires `GenericRepository<T>` to implement `IDisposable`.

It's up to you to decide how you want to design your repositories - I'd opt for the latter. I'd argue its the repository's responsibility to dispose of its' resources.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your first line explicitly says that T must be IDisposable.

Second line says that your GenericRepository must be IDisposable. If that is your intention - yes, your solution is correct.